# Consuming WCF Service with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I have this scenario. 
I have a WCF web service made with C# and I need to consume it with Retrofit on Android. I've searched a lot and found some posts and sites, but I still have problems.

This is my web service file (one of them)

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
    Method = "GET", 
    UriTemplate = @"/Login?UserName={userName}&Password={password}", 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)
]
string Login(string userName, string password);
```

My Web service is running fine, when I call it from the browser I get this response:

```
{"UserList":[{"UserName":"Juan Perez","Active":1,"ProfileName":"Admin"}]}
```

On my Android app I have these files:

**User.java**

```
public class User {
    @SerializedName("UserName")
    @Expose
    private String userName;
    @SerializedName("Active")
    @Expose
    private String active;
    @SerializedName("ProfileName")
    @Expose
    private String profileName;

    public User(String userName, String active, String profileName) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.active =  active;
        this.profileName = profileName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }
    public String getProfileName() {
        return profileName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    public void setProfileName(String profileName) {
        this.profileName = profileName;
    }
}
```

**UserList.java**

```
public class UserList {
    @SerializedName("UserList")
    private ArrayList<User> userList;

    public ArrayList<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(ArrayList<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }
}
```

I have this abstract class for retrofit

```
public abstract class IWebservice {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://mypc.domain.com/Android.svc/";
    public Retrofit retrofit;

    public Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        if(this.retrofit == null) {
            this.retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

I have this other file

```
public interface ILoginService {
    @GET("Login")
    Call<UserList> Login(@Query("UserName") String userName, @Query("Password") String password);
}
```

In here I consume the web service

```
public class Login extends IWebservice {
    public void isValidUser(String userName, String password) {
        ILoginService loginService = getRetrofit().create(ILoginService.class);

        Call<UserList> userData = loginService.Login(userName, password);

        userData.enqueue(new Callback<UserList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserList> call, Response<UserList> response) {
                UserList usersInformation = response.body();

                if(usersInformation.getUserList().size() > 0) {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new Error("Usuario valido" + usersInformation.getUserList().get(0).getUserName()));
                }
                else {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new Error("Usuario Invalido"));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserList> call, Throwable t) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new Error("Error: " + t.getMessage()));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And finally on my MainActivity.java I call it like this:

```
private void doLogin(String userName, String password) {
    Login login = new Login();
    login.isValidUser(userName, password);
}
```

Now, the problem is that I always get a status of 200 (OK) but **response.body()** on Login.java is always null, and I can't find out why, any clues guys?

**Edit**
I added the HttpLoggingInterceptor and got this.

```
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://mypc.domain.com/Android.svc/Login?UserName=JUANP&Password=123456 (102ms)
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: private
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 115
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
D/OkHttp: X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
D/OkHttp: Date: Sat, 04 Aug 2018 22:18:28 GMT
D/OkHttp: {"LoginResult":"{\"UserList\":[{\"UserName\":\"Juan Perez\",\"Active\":1,\"ProfileName\":\"Admin\"}]}"}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (115-byte body)
```

My result is being wrapped in **LoginResult** any idea why? I think this is why I'm having problems.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add another class as

```
public class LoginResult {
    @SerializedName("LoginResult")
    @Expose
    private UserList userList;
}
```

and change your interface as

```
public interface ILoginService {
@GET("Login")
Call< LoginResult > Login(@Query("UserName") String userName, @Query("Password") String password);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I had to change some code on my Web Service, I noticed that I was returning strings, instead of objects (Serializing to Json with Newtonsoft), but this came handy on a real list that I'm returning on another service. .   

Again, thanks a lot